# Maven Javadoc 'Cannot find default setter' and fails

Tags: maven, javadoc, pom.xml

I'm trying to generate javadocs for a maven project, and I'm running into an error every time.
`Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc for parameter #: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.options.Group`.  The command I'm  using is `mvn javadoc:javadoc` from the root directory, where the pom is.

I don't have Groups configured at all, or have any special configuration at all. I get the same error whether I omit the plugin in my pom completely, add it to reporting, or add as a build plugin.  I've tried adding empty groups as well, and while the message changes somewhat, it still appears.

I ran across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441210/maven-3-javadoc-plugin-conflicts-with-testng-groups), but a. I don't have TestNG dependencies, b. I'm not using command line parameters, and c. it was never resolved.

It IS a Selenium project, so I suppose there could be something similar, but I can't figure it out.  Any ideas?  I've included the maven debug stack trace below.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc (default-cli) on project Selenium: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc for parameter #: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.options.Group -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc (default-cli) on project Selenium: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc for parameter #: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.options.Group
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:220)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.3:javadoc for parameter #: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.options.Group
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.javadoc.options.Group
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setDefault(CompositeBeanHelper.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.fromConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.AbstractCollectionConverter.fromChildren(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.convertProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:575)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 3):

That error message indicates that the configurator can't turn a string into an instance.  Instead of doing something like

```
<groups>
  <group>com.example</group>
  ...
</groups>
```

try reworking your groups to look like the [usage example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#groups):

> ```
> <groups>
>   <group>
>     <title>Core Packages</title>
>     <!-- To includes java.lang, java.lang.ref,
>     java.lang.reflect and only java.util
>     (i.e. not java.util.jar) -->
>     <packages>java.lang*:java.util</packages>
>   </group>
>   <group>
>     <title>Extension Packages</title>
>      <!-- To include javax.accessibility,
>     javax.crypto, ... (among others) -->
>     <packages>javax.*</packages>
>   </group>
> </groups>
> ```